# How to get the url names of all requests given in any type of browsers in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to find the urls browsed by the users in a system irrespective of any browser in C#
and i want to store in database in my application.

I made initial search but i didn't get properly.

I tried reading DND Cache.
But it windows-7 it is giving but its is not possible for me to integrate it.
Since it gives all the names at that instant which is alive.
So continously data is repeating.
Moreover unwanted names are also coming.

In Xp if i run that means it not giving propely.

```
 Private Function RunScript(ByVal scriptText As String) As String
    Dim MyRunSpace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
    MyRunSpace.Open()
    Dim MyPipeline As Pipeline = MyRunSpace.CreatePipeline()
    MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText)
    MyPipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String")
    Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = MyPipeline.Invoke()
    MyRunSpace.Close()
    Dim MyStringBuilder As New StringBuilder()
    For Each obj As PSObject In results
        MyStringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString())
    Next
    Return MyStringBuilder.ToString()
End Function
Private Sub fetchHistory()
    Try
        a = RunScript("ipconfig /displaydns | select-string 'Record Name' | foreach-object { $_.ToString().Split(' ')[-1]}")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is the code i tried in VB.

Need help regarding these.

Comment: 1. No one is going to translate VB.NET to C# for you. 2. This is much more complicated than that. You need to create a packet sniffer and/or proxy to monitor all outbound traffic. No an easy task at any level...

Comment: fine don't want translation.while requesting the url through browser internally wt it does and can we able to track through our app if it runs continously ?

Comment: Very unclear what you know to provide concrete answer... See if [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler2/version.asp) is something close to what you are looking for - if yes - read about HTTP protocol and proxies... If not - you'll be able to clarify your question.